# jquery add css to scrolltop function

Tags: jquery

How do I add this ....

$("#otherdiv").css("background-color","yellow");

To trigger with this ....

```
$(function(){
var stickerTop = parseInt($('#header-container').offset().top);
$(window).scroll(function() {
$("#header-container").css((parseInt($(window).scrollTop()) + parseInt($("#header-    container").css('margin-top')) > stickerTop) ? {
        position: 'fixed',
        top: '0px'
    } : {
        position: 'relative'
    }); 
});
});//]]>
```

Many thanks !

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, assuming that you want the `#otherdiv` to receive a background colour when the window is scrolled, try:

```
$(function(){
    var stickerTop = parseInt($('#header-container').offset().top);
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var bg_color = (parseInt($(window).scrollTop()) + parseInt($("#header-container").css('margin-top')) > stickerTop) ? 'yellow' : 'white';
        $("#otherdiv").css("background-color", bg_color);

        $("#header-container").css((parseInt($(window).scrollTop()) + parseInt($("#header-container").css('margin-top')) > stickerTop) ? {
            position: 'fixed',
            top: '0px'
        } : {
            position: 'relative'
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer - I tried this and whilst it does indeed change the CSS on scroll, I need it specifically to change at the same point that the #header-container div is changed to position : fixed ? Thanks for your help..

Comment: So you want to add the CSS only when the `position: fixed` rule is applied, correct?

Comment: that is throwing an error on this line
    var bg_color = ((parseInt($(window).scrollTop()) + parseInt($("#header-container").css('margin-top')) > stickerTop) ? 'yellow' : 'white';

Comment: That's awesome man, works perfectly! Can you run me through briefly what is going on here if poss... I thought it would be a case of simply adding "  $("#otherdiv").css("background-color","yellow");    " somewhere but this is obvs incorrect - what would the equivalant be for adding a top margin onto #otherdiv instead of changing colour? Thanks

Comment: Basically, it uses a ternary operator to determine which background colour should be set. The first one is yellow, or white. You should change the setting for `marginTop` and then specify the values in the ternary operator. If it works, you might like to accept the answer :)

Comment: Yes mate that is spot on, thank you so much for your help - really nice work & v informative too !!